# During oracle 10 G installation, the error "you do not have sufficient privileges to write to the disk" comes

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

During oracle 10 G installation in windows 10, the error "you do not have sufficient privileges to write to the disk" comes

Comment: It would appear you don't have the privileges needed to write to the disk. Are you running the installer as an administrator?

Comment: You may want to include the exact version you are trying to install.  I doubt Oracle 10g is certified for Windows 10.  You may need to run Windows 7/XP in a virtual machine to get 10g installed.